# How to pass a value to a function and cont execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and I'm validating the fields "onblur". what I trying to do is that when the user clicks submit make that any field is empty.

What I was trying to do is to pass the value to a function and run that function when the user click "submit" but I'm having a problem in doing that.

can somebody point me in the right direction on how to fix my problem.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="registerForms" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nusernames">Username: <span id="nusernamesErr" class="error">* </span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nusernames" name="nusernames" onblur="validateForm('nusernames')">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nemail">Email: <span id="nemailErr" class="error">* </span></label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nemail" name="nemail" onblur="validateForm('nemail')">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" id="registerButton"> 
</form>
```

JS:

```
function validateForm(id)
{
    var value = document.getElementById(id).value; 
    var ok = true;

    if(value === "" || value == null)
    {
        document.getElementById(id+'Err').innerHTML = "* <img src='images/unchecked.gif'> Field is required";
        ok = false 
        yesNo(ok);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(id+'Err').innerHTML = "* ";
    } 
}

var button = document.getElementById('#registerButton');

button.onclick = function yesNo(ok)
{
    alert("There's something wrong with your information!")
    if(ok == false)
    {
        alert("There's something wrong with your information!")
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to attach the validation on the click event for your submit button I would suggest you to repeat the validation for each input field like you do on blur event.

Moreover, I would suggest you to save the **ok** value as an attribute of each input field. Set those attributes at dom ready to false and change it to true/false in validateForm function.

When submitting it's a good idea to run your valodator function and test for false fields.

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) in order to register a event handler, [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for selecting elements.

The snippet:

```js
function validateForm(id) {
  var value = document.getElementById(id).value;

  if (value === "" || value == null) {
      document.getElementById(id+'Err').innerHTML = "* <img src='images/unchecked.gif'> Field is required";
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('yesNo', 'false');
  } else {
      document.getElementById(id+'Err').innerHTML = "* ";
      document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('yesNo', 'true');
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll('form[name="registerForms"] input:not([type="submit"])').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
      ele.setAttribute('yesNo', 'false');
  });
  document.getElementById('registerButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      var ok = true;

      document.querySelectorAll('form[name="registerForms"] input:not([type="submit"])').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
          validateForm(ele.id);
          if (ele.getAttribute('yesNo') == 'false') {
              ok = false;
          }
      });

      if (ok == false) {
          console.log("There's something wrong with your information!")
          e.preventDefault();
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" name="registerForms" action="http://www.google.com">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nusernames">Username: <span id="nusernamesErr" class="error">* </span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nusernames" name="nusernames" onblur="validateForm('nusernames')">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nemail">Email: <span id="nemailErr" class="error">* </span></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="nemail" name="nemail" onblur="validateForm('nemail')">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" id="registerButton">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were trying to define var button with this 
    var button = document.getElementById('#registerButton');

but it needs to be this with regular javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('registerButton');
```

That seemed to solve the problem